pgloader does not find sqlite database file
to work myself into pgloader I have created a sqlite3 db from an csv file.
If I open the file and do select star from the data it shows the correct data
path is /tmp/tt.db
this works
sqlite3 /tmp/tt.db

but
pgloader sqlite:///tmp/tt.db

which should work according to the documentation failes with
No such file or directory: "sqlite:///tmp/tt.db"

any idea why ?

Not personally familiar with pgloader, but from the documentation, it appears that if you give it a single argument, it's treated as the name of a script file to read directives from. If you pass it two arguments, the first is treated as a data source, and the second as a connection string that describes the target database you want to import into.

pgloader loads data from various sources into PostgreSQL. It can transform the data it reads on the fly and submit raw SQL before and after the loading. It uses the COPY PostgreSQL protocol to stream the data into the server, and manages errors by filling a pair of reject.dat and reject.log files.
pgloader operates either using commands which are read from files:
pgloader commands.load

or by using arguments and options all provided on the command line:
pgloader SOURCE TARGET


Your example uses only a single argument, so it's looking for that file instead of interpreting the argument as a URI.

uh my comment was gone... that makes unfortunatetly much more sense than the error message ! Thanks for the investigation !
